# Generate list of integers with size n, mean = 20, min=2 and max=25 in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to generate a list of integers with size n, mean = 20, minimum = 2 and maximum = 25.

And tried below code. which is very time consuming.

```
# generate service time with mean = 20, min = 2 and max = 25
def gen_avg(n, expected_avg=20, a=2, b=25):
    while True:
        l = np.random.randint(a, b, size=n)
        avg = np.mean(l)

        if avg == expected_avg:
            return l
```

Please help me with some quick method

Comment: Since your mean does not equal your (max+min)/2 that implies you don't want a uniform distribution. Then you have to specify some other distribution. What distribution do you want to generate samples from?

Comment: Note that such a list must have at least 5 elements (else there's no way to achieve the target min, max and mean). A list of the form `[2, 25, 25, 25, 23, 20, 20, 20, ...]` would work (pad with as many `20`s as you need to get length `n`), but I suspect that's not what you want. What other requirements do you have?

Comment: @MarkDickinson, good point, I think this is the answer !

Comment: @MarkDickinson I would like to have unimodal distribution

Comment: @AKareem I would like to have unimodal distribution or approximated normal distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could generate a random list then slightly tweak the numbers by replacing the numbers that are greater than the mean (if the current mean is too low) or replacing numbers that are less than the mean (if the current mean is too high) like so

```
def gen_avg(n, expected_avg=20, a=2, b=25):
    l = np.random.randint(a, b, size=n)
    while True:
        if np.mean(l) == expected_avg:
            break
        while np.mean(l) > expected_avg:
            c = np.random.choice(np.where(l>expected_avg)[0])
            l[c] = np.random.randint(a, expected_avg+1)
        while np.mean(l) < expected_avg:
            c = np.random.choice(np.where(l<expected_avg)[0])
            l[c] = np.random.randint(expected_avg, b)
        return l
```

This is assuming you don't care about producing from any particularly interesting distribution.